# C# - How do I detect a change in one column between the current DataRow and the Next?

Tags: c#, dataset

I have a query over two tables, SchoolBus and SchoolPupil:

```sql
Select SB.BusNumber, SB.BusDriverLastName, SB.BusDriverFirstName, SP.LastName, SP.FirstName, SP.HomeTown, SP.Age, SP.BusFare 
From SchoolBus As SB 
Inner Join SchoolPupil As SP 
On SP.BusNumber = SB.BusNumber 
Order By SB.BusNumber, SP.HomeTown
```

I need to read that query in my C# application and do rather complicated computations on home town and bus fare for each bus number. That is, for each value of `BusNumber`, I need to work on a set of all the data rows with that value.

Which means I need to detect the last row with a value of `BusNumber`.

It can be done rather simply:

```cs
for (int z_intIdx = 0; z_intIdx < z_dstData.Tables[0].Rows.Count; z_intIdx++)
{
    // do stuff with the DataRow and put it in an IEnumerable for later

    if (z_intIdx == z_dstData.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1 ||
            z_dstData.Tables[0].Rows[z_intIdx] != z_dstData.Tables[0].Rows[z_intIdx + 1])
    {
        // do rather complications with the IEnumerable
    }
}
```

But I can't help feel that there might be a method or property in `DataTable`, `DataRow`, `DataRowCollection` or something else that would be more concise and would let me use a `foreach` or `while` loop.

So, is there something I could use instead of the above code?

Comment: foreach(DataRow row in z_dstData.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()){ }

Comment: as you said you need to "complicated computations on home town and bus fare for each bus number"
I could understand that you want to filter the table with each value of the distinct of bus number and then make the calculation on the home town and bus fare, if that what you want, I believe the fastest way to do that is using linq package
foreach(var value in z_dstData.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().select(x=>x["BusNumber"]).distinct().toList()){
//filter the datatable and do your logic using linq also
}

Comment: @jdweng: I'm not sure how what you propose solves the problem. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: @karamyakoubagha: Aha! I think I can see your point. You're proposing to use Linq to regroup `DataRows` in lists? Now there's an idea...

Comment: @Jean-DavidLanz: Yes exactly, is that what you need? I was not sure of what you want to do

Comment: I just answer how to use a Foreach.  For your issue use GroupBy : dstData.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("BusNumber ").  Add .First() if you only want one.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you! Using Linq and `GroupBy()` worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

With karam yakoub agha and jdweng's help in the comments, I was able to use `GroupBy()` and put the following together:

```cs
foreach (List<DataRow> z_lisPupils in
            z_dstData.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().GroupBy(pu => pu.Field<string>("BusNumber"),
                                                       pu => pu,
                                                       (bus, list) => list.ToList()))
{
    // Now work with z_lisPupils
}
```

I think it should be noted that `Enumerable.GroupBy()` doesn't behave quite the same way as a `Group By` SQL clause does. Assuming it did was part of the reason why I didn't use it before.

Thanks again, people!